# No prime number between number and square of number

Tags: prime-numbers

Find the values of $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that there is no prime number between $x$ and $x^2$. Is there any such number?

Comment: @Shashi: Did you mean to write "the square root of $x$ is $y$ such that $y^2=x$"?

Comment: @Matt: Sorry for typo mistake..

Comment: Bertrand's postulate guarantees the existence of a prime between $n$ and $2n$ for all integers $n > 1$. Therefore there are no non-trivial examples of the phenomenon you describe.

Comment: "Chebyshev said it before, and I say it again, there is always a prime beteween $n$ and $2n$."  -Erdos. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate

Comment: The "logic" tag seems unappropiate.

Comment: I removed the "logic" tag.

Comment: I was going to say this is a dupe, but then I saw the date of posting...

Comment: @JDH, the verse is *about*, but not *by*, Erdos. The author was Nathan Fine.

Answer (score 10):

Despite the comments about Bertrand's postulate, there is still the range $-\sqrt{2} \le x \le \sqrt{2}$. If you want $x$ a natural number, there is $1$ and maybe $0$.

Answer (score 7):

Given the current wording of the question, you can set $x$ to any integer in $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ and there will be no prime between $x$ and $x^2$.  For any other integer $x$, there will always be a prime between $x$ and $x^2$ (as noted in the comments to your question).